# What is the most effective way to preload images in React? Is it worth the effort?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing

I have a website that moves the user forward fairly linearly. And every time the user is moved forward more images are loaded. There appears to be about a second or two delay to load the images into place.

So I started to consider if I could load the images that will be next loaded before the page is changed.

What is the most efficient way to implement this? Is this a common practice? Something worth working towards?

I tried to pass a preLoadedImages Prop and then run this code snippet:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.preLoadImages){
      Object.values(this.props.preLoadImages).forEach((image) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = image.fileName;
      });
    }
  }
```

Currently I do not see images loaded in the network tab until I proceed to the next page still.

Comment: Could you show us how you're passing the prop? Also if this particular component unmounts, you won't have access to the images you previously loaded.

Comment: It is an array of urls to cloudinary where the images are hosted.
The component will unmount before they are displayed. Will the images not be cached?

Comment: this sounds like a lot of tight coupling as the previous and the parent-component now have to know/deal with the images you need preloaded. I'd render the curent view AND the next one off-screen. And on top, this gives you the possibility for a smooth transition *(effect)* for free.

Comment: @thomas Is this a common practice? It seems a little bit hacky, I can see the advantages in this solution. But before I implement it I would like to know this is a widely acceptable solution.

Also how best would I go about hiding it off screen, just an absolute position off the left?

Comment: imo your question is too vague for any common practice. Like asking what's common practice to position a `<div>`. Same for the question on how to "hide it off screen" or better just "hide it". both depends on your special case and may not even be the one solution you could/should use throughout your entire application. There are plenty of ways to hide some content from the eye; everything except of `display:none` may be a possibility. like `position:absolute/fixed;left:-9999px;`or utilizing `overflow:hidden`, etc.. So, as always ... it depends.

Comment: Fair enough. As you mentioned I don't want to have to give to give the preload images to both the component and the prev component. So would this solution work?
 Case 0:
<Page 1>
<Page 2 className=”hidden”>
Case 1:
<Page 2>
<Page 3 className=”hidden”>
Or would this solution do unnecessary rerendering?